# How to suppress Spark logging in unit tests?

Tags: scala, log4j, apache-spark

So thanks to easily googleable blogs I tried:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class SparkEngineSpecs extends Specification {
  sequential

  def setLogLevels(level: Level, loggers: Seq[String]): Map[String, Level] = loggers.map(loggerName => {
    val logger = Logger.getLogger(loggerName)
    val prevLevel = logger.getLevel
    logger.setLevel(level)
    loggerName -> prevLevel
  }).toMap

  setLogLevels(Level.WARN, Seq("spark", "org.eclipse.jetty", "akka"))

  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Test Spark Engine"))

  // ... my unit tests
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work, I still get a lot of spark output, e.g.:

```
14/12/02 12:01:56 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_4 of size 4184 dropped from memory (free 583461216)
14/12/02 12:01:56 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned broadcast 4
14/12/02 12:01:56 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned shuffle 4
14/12/02 12:01:56 INFO ShuffleBlockManager: Deleted all files for shuffle 4
```

Comment: After trying all solutions below, you can still find the logging level untouched. In that case, be sure that spark is higher in the list of dependencies in the pom.xml to prevent any other jar injecting a log4j2.properties file on the spark classpath with behavior you do not want.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add the following code into the `log4j.properties` file inside the `src/test/resources` dir, create the file/dir if  not exist

```
# Change this to set Spark log level
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN

# Silence akka remoting
log4j.logger.Remoting=WARN

# Ignore messages below warning level from Jetty, because it's a bit verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
```

When I run my unit tests (I'm using JUnit and Maven), I only receive WARN level logs, in other words no more cluttering with INFO level logs (though they can be useful at times for debugging).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Works for SBT with specs2

Comment: thanks @Emre. it worked like charm for java in intelliJ idea.

Comment: With new versions use log4j2.properties (specially 2.4.0)

Answer (score 10):

In my case one of my own libraries brought logback-classic into the mix. This materialized in a warning at the start:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/alex/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/alex/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

I solved this by excluding it from the dependency:

```
"com.mystuff" % "mylib" % "1.0.0" exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic")
```

Now I could add a `log4j.properties` file in `test/resources` which now gets used by Spark.

Answer (score 7):

After some time of struggling with Spark log output as well, I found a [blog post](https://engineering.sharethrough.com/blog/2015/06/04/suppressing-slf4j-logs-during-tests-in-sbt/) with a solution I particularly liked.

If you use slf4j, one can simply exchange the underlying log implementation. A good canidate for the test scope is slf4j-nop, which carfully takes the log output and puts it where the sun never shines.

When using Maven you can add the following to the top of your dependencies list:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.12</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that it might be important to have it at the beginning of the dependencies list to make sure that the given implementations are used instead of those that might come with other packages (and which you can consider to exclude in order to keep your class path tidy and avoid unexpected conflicts).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a separate Logback config for tests. Depending on your environment it's possible that you just need to create `conf/logback-test.xml` with something that hides the logs. I think this should do that:

```
<configuration>
  <root level="debug">
  </root>
</configuration>
```

As I understand it, this captures all logs (level `debug` and higher) and assigns no logger to them, so they get discarded. A better option is to configure a file logger for them, so you can still access the logs if you want to.

See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html for the detailed documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I tried adding a file in "src/test/resources/conf" called "logback-test.xml" with the contents you provide (tried with level "warn" too), but it had no effect :(

Comment: I'm really unsure about all this, sorry. But our project directs logs to a file during tests, so we just need to figure out how it's set up :). `logback-test.xml` is in `<project root>/conf` here. The file is not mentioned anywhere in our source, so it's possibly a magical default location. I don't see anything else... If I delete the file I start getting log output (from `warn` up) during tests. We use Scalatest.

Comment: I tried putting it in `proj-root/conf/` no luck.  I'm a little confused how it would ever get picked put since the filename nor contents reference spark.  In the meantime I'm using a really hacky script that does a `grep -v` with a regex that kinda removes the spark logs.

Comment: Paste this into `test/resources/logback.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party but I found this in the [spark example code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/StreamingExamples.scala) :

```
def setStreamingLogLevels() {
    val log4jInitialized = Logger.getRootLogger.getAllAppenders.hasMoreElements
    if (!log4jInitialized) {
        // We first log something to initialize Spark's default logging, then we override the
        // logging level.
        logInfo("Setting log level to [WARN] for streaming example." +
        " To override add a custom log4j.properties to the classpath.")
        Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
    }
}
```

I also found that with your code if you call setLogLevels like below it cut out alot of out put for me.

```
setLogLevels(Level.WARN, Seq("spark", "org", "akka"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution working for me is:

```
cp $SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties.template $YOUR_PROJECT/src/test/resources/log4j.properties
sed -i -e 's/log4j.rootCategory=INFO/log4j.rootCategory=WARN/g' $YOUR_PROJECT/src/test/resources/log4j.properties
```